# `advise` Environment in listings package

Tags: macros, listings, environments

I was reading the [documentation for the latex listings package](ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) and there are *advises* in it which look like so:

[image: advise-environment in the listings documentation]

I had a quick look in [the source code for the documentation](ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.dtx) and it turns out that there is an `advise` environment:

```
\begin{advise}
\item Must I do that really?
    \advisespace
    Yes and no. Some books about programming say this is good.
```

It seems to be defined inside the package:

```
% \begin{environment}{advise}
% \begin{macro}{\advisespace}
% The environment uses |\@listi|.
%    \begin{macrocode}
 \def\advise{\par\list\labeladvise
    {\advance\linewidth\@totalleftmargin
     \@totalleftmargin\z@
     \@listi
     \let\small\footnotesize \small\sffamily
     \parsep \z@ \@plus\z@ \@minus\z@
     \topsep6\p@ \@plus1\p@\@minus2\p@
     \def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}}}
\let\endadvise\endlist
%    \end{macrocode}
%    \begin{macrocode}
\def\advisespace{\hbox{}\qquad}
\def\labeladvise{$\to$}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
% \end{environment}
```

However, neither do I understand this code snippet nor do I get this to work (copy and paste does not work, and I do not know what the code in comments means).

Is there maybe an `advise`-package out there? Is there a way to get this piece of code working outside of the listings package? If so, how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code for `advise` is actually written as an *environment*, even though there's no `\newenvironment` syntax. That's because the author defined the start `\advise` and end `\endadvise` components separately. Regardless, `advise` is a `list` environment, and a `list` takes two arguments that specifies some of the parameters and labelling styles. Nowadays most people use packages to manipulate labels and spacing (like [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)), but this can still be defined using the TeX fundamentals. For the specifics regarding `\list`, see [`source2e.pdf`](http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf) (section **56 List, and related environments**, p 218). Here's an extract:

```
\list{<label>}{<commands>} ... \endlist
```

where `<label>` is `\labeladvise` and `<commands>` contain all the spacing and `\makelabel` commands/redefinitions.

The commented out code is a style for writing packages that are self-contained in terms of their code (`.sty`) and documentation (`.tex` and `.pdf`). Typically these packages are written as a `.dtx` & `.ins` pair, that is processed into various output files. See [How do I install a `.dtx` file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6925/5764) or [Can I convert a `.dtx` file to `.tex` file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29763/5764).

Here's an example using the code:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\advise{\par\list\labeladvise
  {\advance\linewidth\@totalleftmargin
   \@totalleftmargin\z@
   \@listi
   \let\small\footnotesize \small\sffamily
   \parsep \z@ \@plus\z@ \@minus\z@
   \topsep6\p@ \@plus1\p@\@minus2\p@
   \def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}}}
\let\endadvise\endlist
\def\advisespace{\hbox{}\qquad}
\def\labeladvise{$\to$}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{advise}
  \item Must I do that really?
    \advisespace
    Yes and no. Some books about programming say this is good.
\end{advise}
\end{document}
```

Note the use of `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, since you're using `@` as part of your macros. See [What do `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/5764)