# How are the command names on the side in CTAN docs typeset

Tags: geometry, marginpar

Trying to figure out how they place the command names on the left margin on package docs on CTAN, e.g.

[image]

I have tried using `marginpar`, but my text is not properly aligned. Minimal example:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,left=6cm,top=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\begin{document}

\reversemarginpar\marginpar{\raggedright SomeCommand}%
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Obviously, the text on the left is not aligned to the first line of the paragraph, which is the desired effect. I am also interested in having the text on the left to use `\ttfamily`.

How should I proceed?

Comment: many packages use the `doc` package (or `ltxdoc` class which uses `doc`.) The source for every document is available at the same place (`minted.dtx` in this example)

Comment: I should've probably mentioned I am not documenting a Latex package, but an API of mine. I noticed the `doc` package exposes things strictly related to documenting other Latex packages. Is that the way to go for me?

Comment: well `doc` is almost certainly the answer of the question you asked, but it may not be the answer for  your real use case as it is rather specialised for tex packages. You may prefer a basic description list and use `enumitem` package to adjust the layout to your requirements

Comment: i might be just dumb, but can't seem to figure it out. would you be able to provide an example, please?

Comment: Use the `DescribeMacro` macro. Search for an example in any dtx file (or in this [unrelated answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/638750/250119) for an example that is usable in "normal TeX files" i.e. one that doesn't "comment out every lines".

Comment: You may also want to have a look at the `documentation` library of [tcolorbox](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The alignment is messed up because marginpar is being invoked in vertical mode.  A `\leavevmode` remedies the issue.  As to `\ttfamily`, it can just be added to the marginpar.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,left=6cm,top=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\begin{document}

\leavevmode\reversemarginpar\marginpar{\raggedright\ttfamily SomeCommand}%
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you wish to get the backslash for a command name in such a context, just use the `\char'134` primitive, as in

```
\leavevmode\reversemarginpar\marginpar{\raggedright\ttfamily\char'134
 SomeCommand}
```

Comment: \char`\\ should work as well (although it's nearly impossible to type correctly in one of these comments).

Comment: @barbarabeeton Just type ``​`​`\char`\\`​​`​`` to get ``\char`\\``.

Comment: @user202729 -- I'm pretty sure I did try that, with incorrect results, but maybe I fumbled something.  Anyhow, thanks.  (I prefer this formulation because it's lot's easier to remember than a number.)

Answer (score 4):

To answer the question in the title, use `DescribeMacro`. (see the documentation source code for any package to see how it's done. While it doesn't start with a backslash, it appears to work here.)

```
%! TEX program = pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{doc}
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\begin{document}

\DescribeMacro{SomeCommand}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

An image of the output isn't very important, but it's below.

[image: image of the output]