# Where to find a "CTAN Package Documentation" like template

Tags: templates, ctan, lineno

I need to write a formal document, with numbered lines (package `lineno`) and with some particular "float" out of paragraph margins.

I found that the **CTAN package documentation** style is perfect for my needs, like the one I'm posting here:

[image: CTAN Template]

Do you guys know if there's a CTAN style template I can download for my personal use?

Thank you,
Rosario

Comment: you don't need to download anything that is `doc` package layout, part of the core `base` latex distribution. See the source `hanging.dtx`of the document you show.

Comment: https://www.texdev.net/2009/10/06/a-model-dtx-file/

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I probably should write a new one of those ...

Comment: Dear @DavidCarlisle, thank you for your answers. which basically solved the question. Just one more related question: in this `.dtx` file there's a macro called `macrocode` which allows to write code within the line numbering. What if I want the line numbering in the whole document and not only in the `macrocode` portion? Thank you, Rosario

Comment: you could try adding `lineno` package but I'm not sure it would make sense: the line numbers in `macrocode` are numbering code lines and relate to the package files that will be extracted, the numbering of general paragraph text lines in the pdf after linebreaking to the text width is a rather different thing and doing both in the same document sounds confusing.

Comment: See also: [geometry - How are the command names on the side in CTAN docs typeset - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/649039/how-are-the-command-names-on-the-side-in-ctan-docs-typeset)

Comment: Thank you for your answers. @DavidCarlisle I tried adding the lineno package and it doesn't produce any effect. The `macrocode` macro and then the `describemacro` command are a black box that I can't customize unfortunately. 

I've read the link posted by @user202729, very useful actually! The problem that guy has is exactly the same I have: customize the text to the left of each starting paragraph. Now I have something like this ![pdf bad](https://it.overleaf.com/read/jhkwjtgshgzg)