# How to write a user manual for a class in two languages?

Tags: languages, documentation

Most classes and packages on ctan, offer a `.dtx` file, which when processed will automatically produce a user manual. In most cases such classes use the author's mother language. As for example [yfont](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/yfonts/)s is written in German. In my opinion any such classes and packages they should offer documentation at least in English as well as a second language. This can be done by either the author or one of the many volunteers.

Is there a convention or a recommended convention for doing so? Can one give an example, how to go about for example extending the `yfonts` documentation to English? What about if a third language is introduced, cramming everything into the `.dtx` file would render it unreadable. Using `babel` and Beamer's `translate`, would be tedious and prone to errors when the primary author makes an update. Do we need an extension to `docstrip` for this?

Comment: Looks related: [Is it possible to keep my translation together with original text?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5076/is-it-possible-to-keep-my-translation-together-with-original-text)

Comment: @MartinScharrer They are actually totally unrelated, if you read both questions carefully:). The link you point to had a one macro answer, where I am looking to find a solution to the whole text of a package, i.e., all the stuff that end up in the manual.

Comment: Both Charles's or my answer there work with full paragraphs or complete documents.

Comment: One should distinguish between package documentation and code documentation. You're talking about the latter, aren't you?

Comment: @egreg Yes, sorry if I was not very clear. For most packages is the same though.

Comment: @MartinScharrer I am after how do you handle `% Die Schriftfamilie "Gotisch"':
%    \begin{macrocode}
\DeclareFontFamily{LYG}{ygoth}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LYG}{ygoth}{m}{n}{%
<10><10.95><12><14.4><17.28><20.74><24.88>ygoth}{}
%    \end{macrocode}
%` in two languages. I am specifically asking, if there is a solution for `.dtx'` files.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides I'd say code should only be documented in one language. A good package has user documentation for 'everyone else', and the code comments are really for the developers. It's not realistic to write those comments in multiple languages, but more importantly its encouraging the idea that users should be reading these comments: they should not need to. (This applies even to 'programming support' packages, where it's still important to have 'user' documentation, but for user programmers.)

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: Ok, I was thinking you are talking about the user documentation part, not the code documentation. IMHO, there is no reason at all to have the code documentation in any other language than English, besides the one that the author isn't able to speak/write English. I also highly disagree that "for most pages is the same". There are a thankfully only a few that mix the user and code documentation, which IMHO means they don't have a proper user documentation! Both should be separated.

Comment: there seems to be an assumption that *anyone* can write in english; this is fine for me, but not so for many ctan contributors.  why is it appropriate to require people to write in a language they can hardly understand?  if i were required to document my packages in russian, i would have taken years longer to develop my packages.  why should a russian-speaker be expected to document in english?

Comment: @Anon: Because english is the de facto _lingua_ _franca_. User documentation should be in english if possible, code documentation is best done in a language the author is comfortable with.

Comment: @MartinSchröder *english is the de facto lingua franca* is fantastic if you think about the words' origins!!

Answer (score 1):

There is no a straightforward way to do it. But you can do in two steps:

1. Convert the document `.dtx` to `.tex` as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16861/how-can-i-pull-an-example-out-of-a-dtx-file/16948#16948).
2. Use [po4a](http://po4a.alioth.debian.org/man/man7/po4a.7.php) for translating text chains and create a new `.tex` document in another language.